# Creating a proper schema for a spark-streaming RDD

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working with a dstream coming from kafka that looks like the record below. I have been struggling getting the proper schema setup with the nested JSON fields.  Here is a sample of what I am doing. What im missing is the ability to just get the actual value rather than a array or a rdd type.  Appreciate any help.

```
{"Source":"10.30.110.45:42757","Telemetry":{"node_id_str":"ASR9006","subscription_id_str":"qos","encoding_path":"Cisco-IOS-XR-infra-statsd-oper:infra-statistics/interfaces/interface/latest/data-rate","collection_id":30905218,"collection_start_time":1524503864744,"msg_timestamp":1524503864744,"collection_end_time":1524503864746},"Rows":[{"Timestamp":1524503864746,"Keys":{"interface-name":"Bundle-Ether56"},"Content":{"bandwidth":40000000,"input-data-rate":4300587,"input-load":27,"input-packet-rate":5375721,"load-interval":0,"output-data-rate":12,"output-load":0,"output-packet-rate":5,"peak-input-data-rate":0,"peak-input-packet-rate":0,"peak-output-data-rate":0,"peak-output-packet-rate":0,"reliability":255}}]}
```

and the code looks like the following:

```
val schema_array = StructType (Array(
        StructField("Source",StringType),
        StructField("Telemetry",StructType(Array(
          StructField("collection_end_time",LongType),
          StructField("collection_id",LongType),
          StructField("collection_start_time",LongType),
          StructField("encoding_path",StringType),
          StructField("msg_timestamp",LongType),
          StructField("node_id_str",StringType),
          StructField("subscription_id_str",StringType)
        ))),
          StructField("Rows",ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("Timestamp",LongType),
            StructField("Keys",StructType(Array(
              StructField("interface-name",StringType)))),
            StructField("Content",StructType(Array(
            StructField("bandwidth",LongType),
            StructField("input-data-rate",LongType),
            StructField("input-load",LongType),
            StructField("input-packet-rate",LongType),
            StructField("load-interval",LongType),
            StructField("output-data-rate",LongType),
            StructField("output-load",LongType),
            StructField("output-packet-rate",LongType),
            StructField("peak-input-data-rate",LongType),
            StructField("peak-input-packet-rate",LongType),
            StructField("peak-output-data-rate",LongType),
            StructField("peak-output-packet-rate",LongType),
            StructField("reliability",LongType))))))))))

    stream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time)  =>
        val data = rdd.map (record => record.value)
        val jsonData = spark.read.schema(schema_array).json(data)

        val result = jsonData.select("Rows.Keys.interface-name")
        result.show()
```

My result is:

```
+----------------+
|  interface-name|
+----------------+
|[Bundle-Ether56]|
+----------------+
```

Expected Result is:

```
+----------------+
|  interface-name|
+----------------+
| Bundle-Ether56 |
+----------------+
```

`

Answer (score 1):

After digging around for awhile I found that the explode method seemed to work for what im looking to do.  I believe since im doing a forEach and only getting one record at a time I am safe flattening my record.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
  val result = jsonData.select(explode($"Rows.Keys.interface-name"))
    result.show()
```

Result

```
+--------------+
|           col|
+--------------+ 
|Bundle-Ether56|
+--------------+
```